# Ubuntu is very slow on esxi5

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-esxi, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 32bit on Vmware esxi 5 update 1.

The virtual machine is: 2 core, 4 GB RAM, 64 MB VGA.

Still the vm is very very slow (with and without the vmware tools) . What could be causing this?

Thank you.

---

**update 1:**

I didn't write the specs of the server since it is really powerful, and not really doing a lot currently, all other machines (some windows and some linux redhat) work great.

By slow, I mean everything is slow, login, any UI action, anything I do is slow.
Moving the mouse is slow, right click takes about 5 secs to appear. Except that booting is really fast.
If I should test something specific, let me know.

*The physical servers specs:*

I am on 2 servers connected with vsphere each:

- 2 CPUs with 16 physical cores/ 32 logical core
- 32 GB RAM

I have tried to use Unity 2D instead of the default. but nothing changed. I tried using only one core not 2 as someone suggested but nothing changed.

---

**Update 2**

I thought I have all vmware tools installed, but checking the additional drivers, told me I have an additional driver not activated, so I did activate it.

I have also downloaded gnome classic.

Both these changes made the vm a bit better. Still the UI is lagging and too slow. The processing itself is good however.

Comment: More details please, what's the host hardware, how contended is it, how is it 'slow'?

Comment: Why am I getting down voted?

Comment: Thanks everybody, the management have decided to move out of ubuntu. I won't be able to investigate anything.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of steps you can take to slowly figure out what the issue might be.  I would first check if there are any available alerts and look at the hosts statistics to see how the system is running (CPU, Memory, etc.).  This will go a long way to helping figure out the issue.  **Otherwise "slow" isn't really a good description for anyone to help solve an issue**.  If you have other VM's installed on the host check to see how they are running.  Is your VM on the same datastore as all your other VM's?  What are the specs of your host machine?

Comment: Please, check my update. And there is no errors in esx.

Comment: @AhHatem Where is the server from a network perspective?  From what you've described, the VM is fine, it's just your interactions with it that are slow.  Do you have a high speed, low latency network connection to the server that hosts the VM?

Comment: Yes, I am on LAN, and I am using the exact same link to handle other VMs just fine.